# ODBC Connection to Excel file - override determined data type

Tags: c#, excel, odbc

There are a couple other questions on this subject, but the answers I've seen reference the Text file driver, whereas I'm using an xlsx file.  Anyway, here's the issue:

Is there a way to override the ODBC-determined data type in a C# program pulling data from Excel?  The data type is coming through as a number seemingly because the row scan is showing most of the data as a number, whereas it's meant to be processed as alphanumeric.  All text data is coming through as NULL with the `ODBCDataReader.GetValue(int)` method.

Here's the basic structure of the code:

```
public static void test()
{
    OdbcDataReader DataReader;
    try
    {
        using (OdbcConnection ODBC_Connection = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" + filename))
        {

            ODBC_Connection.Open();
            OdbcCommand Command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]", ODBC_Connection);

            Command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            DataReader = Command.ExecuteReader();

            while (DataReader.Read())
            {
                field0 = DataReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                field1 = DataReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                field2 = DataReader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                field3 = DataReader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                field4 = DataReader.GetValue(4).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

`field4` is the field in question, and all the data for the other fields are passing properly through the `.GetValue(int)` method.

How can I override the data type for this field prior to the SELECT statement?  Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a `DataReader.GetString()` method? If that does not work you can prefix the 4th column with a single quote `'` and it should be treated as text

Comment: Reference for the [**.GetString()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @mehow: Since the SELECT query doesn't pull in any data for that field (it is NULL), the `.GetString()` call throws an exception.

Comment: I see, this is quite strange. Have you tried using ADO instead of ODBcDataReader?

Comment: I was hoping to make minor changes to the existing ODBC connection instead of implementing something new, but it might end up coming down to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, but I believe I resolved this by using an OLEDB connection instead of ODBC.